# LinkedList prints same values

Tags: c, linked-list

I am currently learning C and I facing a Linked List situation which I really do not understand it.

I created the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct list
{
    int age;
    char name[256];
    struct list *next;
};

void displayList ( struct list *node );

int main( void )
{
    struct list *node = malloc ( sizeof ( struct list ) );

    node->age = 10;
    strcpy( node->name, "Kiara" );

    node->next = malloc ( sizeof ( struct list ) );
    node->next->next = NULL;

    displayList( node );

    free( node->next );
    free( node );
}

void displayList ( struct list *node )
{
    int i = 0;
    struct list *current = node;
    while ( current != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%d) - Age = %d\n%d) - Name = %s\n",i , node->age, i, node->name );
        i++;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

And when the `displayList()` is calling I was expecting to get something like this:

```
0) - Age = 10
0) - Name = Kiara

1) - Age = GARBAGE
1) - Name = GARBAGE
```

But instead I got:

```
0) - Age = 10
0) - Name = Kiara

1) - Age = 10
1) - Name = Kiara
```

What I am doing/understanding wrong here?

Comment: Who says that garbage can't be equal to `10` and `Kiara`?

Comment: Nobody, but it is not very likely. See answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are printing node values in the loop but should print current values. The node pointer does not change.

```
node->age, node->name
```

Should be:

```
current->age, current->name
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In your loop here:

```
while ( current != NULL )
{
    printf( "Age = %d\nName = %s\n", node->age, node->name );
    current = current->next;
}
```

you always print `node->name`, while it should be `current->name`:

```
 printf( "Age = %d\nName = %s\n", current->age, current->name );
```

The pointer `node` never changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
1) - Age = GARBAGE
1) - Name = GARBAGE
```

You are expecting garbage to be printed, but don't expect that. Accessing uninitiated variable is actually undefined behavior. On most implementation they print garbage but in reality anything may happen (e.g. a run time crash). Even if the implementation doesn't crash upon trying to access uninitialized variable you may face problem while printing garbage.

```
printf("%s", str);
```

This expects a null terminated string. If your random garbage data do not contain a `\0` then again you will get a run time crash.

You are not printing the data of `current` in loop (which is already pointed by other answers).

```
printf( "%d) - Age = %d\n%d) - Name = %s\n",i , current->age, i, current->name );
```

Comment: I cannot Up Vote you , because I need 15 rep.

Comment: @Khaled that perfectly okay as long as you understand what I tried to say.